# jquery validation working only after CTRL+F5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

I'm struggling with jQuery mobile. 
I've created a standard MVC-4 C# project and customized that, overall it's working very nice, but there are some specifics I cannot seem to get right.

When I log in to the application the product-selection is shown but my URL still points to /Account/Login, so doing a refresh on that page results in a login-form. Also trying to view the source doesn't show me the list but the login form html.

Then after selecting a product from a list of  only then does the URL change to /product/1 and at that point then the validation (using data-annotations) doesn't work, however after doing a refresh using CTRL+F5 the validation DOES work correctly...

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here but it's driving me nuts, I've been searching/googling this for hours now and I've changed the sequence of validation scripts in bundles but as I said it works after a refresh so I guess the load-sequence of the scripts is pretty much correct. I've also read that the URL problem has something to do with ajax handling the logon.

I'm not sure what parts of my code/html to show here, so just ask and I will post it.

- Jquery 1.8.2
- Jquery Mobile 1.3.1

thanks,
Jurjen.

Comment: Did you included all the necessary javascript files in all templates?

Comment: @grigno, as far as I know I did include all js files in the templates, I would guess that if I didn't it wouldn't work at all, not even after refresh / CTRL+F5